# Swift insert big height label into view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I'm new to the Swift and trying to add label programmatically to UIView which is embedded into scroll view.

Actually, i want to have something with header (picture and title for half of the screen) and content below (text with unknown length and images).

I'm added a view container and depending on content i want to add label or image view.
Most of the time it will be like that:

```
text
image
text
image
```

and so on.

Add label code (Swift 4):

```
let label = UILabel()

label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = blogItem.text
containerView.addSubview(label)

label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

The problem is that text is truncated, when comes to the end of the screen and no scrolling at all.

How can i add bottom constraint correctly (i believe that's all happens because of it?) to make expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you created a proper hierarchy for working `UIScrollView`:

1. Add a `scrollView` to the hierarchy and use autolayout to properly layout it, e.g., if it is supposed to cover the whole `view` of the `viewController`:

   ```
   scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
       scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
       scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
       scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
   ])
   ```
2. Then you need to add a `contentView` to the `scrollView` and provide a proper layout constraints for it, so if you want vertically scrollable `scrollView` in the example I started above, you need following autolayout constraints:

   ```
   contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       // horizontal anchors of contentView are constrained to scrollView superview
       // to prevent it from scrolling horizontally
       contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor),
       contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor),
       // but vertical anchors of contentView are constrained to
       // scrollView to allow scrolling
       contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
       contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
   ])
   ```

   Notice here that I constrained the `leftAnchor` and `rightAnchor` of the `contentView` to the `self.view` rather than to `scrollView` to make it of fixed width. However, top and bottom anchors are constrained to the scrollView, so they are expanded and scrollable when `contentView` needs more space.
3. Now you add to the `contentView` all the content that you want, and you lay it out using autolayout as if the `contentView` was a view with infinite height - `scrollView` will take care of presenting it whole by scrolling. So in my example if the only content would be one huge `UILabel` with many lines (`label` is a subview of `contentView`):

   ```
   label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor),
       label.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor),
       label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
       label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
   ])
   ```

Try to go over your code and check your constraints. It might be that you miss constraints in both cases, and the fact that it works in first case is just a coincidence.

Comment: Can i have all constraints, except views that i add programmatically (labels, imageviews), have in storyboard?
my scheme: http://prntscr.com/i5ffqj

Comment: storyboards - code, it does not matter, if you do the hierarchy and constraints right.. from your screenshot I can tell that you put several views in the `scrollView`.. I have never try that, I would use one `contentView` (as described above), to which I would put all the content views (labels, imageViews, views, etc.).. you can do the same thing I described in my answer using storyboards

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i5fxw4
I embed everything in scrollview in one view, but still i don't know how set constraints in storyboard, to not disable scroll.
http://prntscr.com/i5fxw4

Comment: I found what was wrong, XCode suggest me to center my container in scrollview (showing errors without it).
I deleted view.centerY = centerY and not deleted view.centerX = centerX and now its fine. Thanks